Get a SSL Certificate Error while calling OPENAI Api to run a few agents
Executing a CrewAI Agent call to OpenAI:
result = crew.kickoff(inputs={"topic": "Artificial Intelligence"})

from IPython.display import Markdown
Markdown(result)

I get a

APIConnectionError: Connection error

with a number of underlying SSL Cert verifications like the ones below.
I noticed I get this error in my Anaconda Jupyter Notebook as well my VSCode editor. I don't get these running on Lightning AI editor online.
I used a Macbook pro. My initial suspicion is the Certs installed on my KeyChain but not sure which one to fix and how.
Any pointers why this happens?
 - ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py:10, in map_exceptions(map)
      9 try:
---> 10     yield
     11 except Exception as exc:  # noqa: PIE786


SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectError                              
Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py:67, in map_httpcore_exceptions()
     66 try:
---> 67     yield
     68 except Exception as exc:


ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectError                              
Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py:952, in SyncAPIClient._request(self, cast_to, options, remaining_retries, stream, stream_cls)
    951 try:
--> 952     response = self._client.send(
    953         request,
    954         stream=stream or self._should_stream_response_body(request=request),
    955         **kwargs,
    956     )
    957 except httpx.TimeoutException as err:


File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py:84, in map_httpcore_exceptions()
     83 message = str(exc)
---> 84 raise mapped_exc(message) from exc

ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLCertVerificationError                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py:10, in map_exceptions(map)
      9 try:
---> 10     yield
     11 except Exception as exc:  # noqa: PIE786

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ssl.py:1108, in SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1107             raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1108         self.do_handshake()
   1109 except (OSError, ValueError):

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ssl.py:1383, in SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)
   1382         self.settimeout(None)
-> 1383     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1384 finally:

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectError                              
Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py:67, in map_httpcore_exceptions()
     66 try:
---> 67     yield
     68 except Exception as exc:

I am running a crew of 3 agents making calls to openAI to plan, write and edit a blog. However connection error prevents this from happening.

This issue is resolved, turns out CrewAI uses OpenAI embeddings by default. I had set memory to true without specifying transformer explicitly while specifying use of LLAMA3 as the model. Once I changed the code to use another explicit transformer, execution was seamless.
Here is the code change made to sort out the issue. Not sure why the API connection was being thrown. Turns out it was not due to a SSL Connection error.
   /* Code changed in the API Call */

crew = Crew(
    agents=[planner, writer, editor],
    tasks=[plan, write, edit],
    verbose=2,
    memory=True,
        **embedder={
            "provider": "huggingface",
            "config": {
                "model": "mixedbread-ai/mxbai-embed-large-v1", # https://huggingface.co/mixedbread-ai/mxbai-embed-large-v1
            }**
        }
) 


This is generally due to Crew-AI defaulting to Chat GPT 4 version, which requires a Plus or higher subscription from OpenAI. This can be solved either using a different model such as Hugging Face or Ollama, or just having a OpenAI Plus or higher subscription.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
